# Error: CSRF token mismatch in cakephp 3.6.10

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Im making a simple select change. But I have a problem ang getting the following error:

```
Error: [Cake\Http\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException] CSRF token mismatch.
```

This is my function on the controller:

```
public function municipios() {

$this->viewBuilder()->layout('ajax');
$this->LoadModel('Municipios');
$subregion = $this->request->getData['subregion_id'];


    $municipios = $this->Municipios->find('list',[
        'limit' => 200,

        'conditions' => ['Municipios.subregion_id' => $subregion],
        'contain' => ['Subregiones']

       ]);

    $this->set(compact('municipios'));
    $this->set('_serialize', 'municipios');

}
```

This is my jquery ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#subregion-id").bind("change",
    function (event) {
      $.ajax({
    async:true,
    data: $("#subregion-id").serialize(),
    dataType:"html",
    success:
    function (data, textStatus) {
      $("#municipio-id").html(data);
      },
      type:"post", url:"\/lavaderos\/municipios"});
  return false;
      });
  });
```

I read on the documentation that need a token but I dont know how to do it.

That code work fine in 3.5.x but no in 3.6.x

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can resolve this by sending you CSRF token through a special X-CSRF-Token header in your ajax call. https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/csrf.html

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#subregion-id").bind("change",
    function (event) {
      $.ajax({
    async:true,
    data: $("#subregion-id").serialize(),
    dataType:"html",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) { // Add this line
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('[name="_csrfToken"]').val());
    },  // Add this line
    success:function (data, textStatus) {
      $("#municipio-id").html(data);
    },
      type:"post", url:"\/lavaderos\/municipios"});
  return false;
      });
  });
```

**OR**

You can disable CSRF component[Not recommended by the Cakephp] for your ajax action like:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
     if (in_array($this->request->action, ['ajaxEdit'])) {
         $this->eventManager()->off($this->Csrf);
     }
 }
```

Comment: @JoseRafaelCamejo Great. Please accept the answer. This will help the others.

Comment: @JoseRafaelCamejo
first solution dose not work for me . it seems 
`$('[name="_csrfToken"]').val()` dose not have any value . it returned `undefined` in `console.log()`

Comment: You can add this to your view if it returns undefined: ```<input type="hidden" name="_csrfToken" value="<?= $this->request->getParam('_csrfToken'); ?>" />```